# action result is published, but callback not being called

Tags: ros, callback, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I must have set up my callback wrong, but I've followed the tutorials and cannot find the issue.

It's a relatively simple example.

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<face_detector::FaceDetectorAction> ActionClient;

ValveInspection::ValveInspection()
{
    valve_client = new ActionClient ("valve_inspection_classifier", false);
}

void ValveInspection::activeCb()
{
    cout << "Active!" << endl;
}

void ValveInspection::doneCb(const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState& state, const face_detector::FaceDetectorResultConstPtr& result)
{
    cout << "Got here!" << endl;
    cout << result->face_positions.size() << endl;
}

void ValveInspection::requestValves()
{
    face_detector::FaceDetectorGoal goal;
    valve_client->sendGoal(goal, boost::bind(&ValveInspection::doneCb, this, _1, _2),boost::bind(&ValveInspection::activeCb, this), ActionClient::SimpleFeedbackCallback());
    cout <<"Sent goal!" << endl;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "valve_inspection");

  ValveInspection* vi = new ValveInspection();

  ros::Rate r = ros::Rate(1);
  while(ros::ok())
  {
    vi->requestValves();
    r.sleep();
  }
}
```

If I subscribe to /valve_inspection_classifier/result, I get results. However, the callback is not being called.

My output from the couts is only:

```
Sent goal!
Sent goal!
Sent goal!
Sent goal!
```

So the activeCb and doneCb are not being called. Can someone shed some light on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238535/action-result-is-published,-but-callback-not-being-called/) by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 211 on 2016-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't forget your ros::spinOnce() if you are going to use a while loop!

[Reference](http://answers.ros.org/question/11887/significance-of-rosspinonce/)

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "valve_inspection");

  ValveInspection* vi = new ValveInspection();

  ros::Rate r = ros::Rate(1);
  while(ros::ok())
  {
    ros::spinOnce();
    vi->requestValves();
    r.sleep();
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) with karma: 211 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1